# Find the probability using the poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Grandma bakes chocolate chip cookies in batches of 100. She puts 300 chips into the dough. When the cookies are done, she gives you one.

1. What is the probability that your cookie contains at least 2 chocolate chips?
2. Grandma decided to add chips to the dough so that only 1% of the cookies will contain no chips. How many chips must she include in a batch of 100 cookies to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable *mathematical model* for the situation is that the number $X$ of chocolate chips in a randomly selected cookie has Poisson distribution with mean $\frac{300}{100}=3$.

So $X$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=3$. It follows that the probability that a cookie contains exactly $k$ chips is 
$$e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.$$
We want $\Pr(X\ge 2)$. We have
$$\Pr(X\ge 2)=1-\Pr(X=0)-\Pr(X=1)=1-e^{-\lambda} -e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda}{1!}.$$

For the second problem, let $n$ be the number of chips she adds to a batch. Then the mean number of chips per cookie is $\frac{n}{100}$. That is our new $\lambda$.

We want the probability of no chips to be $\lt 0.01$. The probability of no chips in a cookie is $e^{-\lambda}$, so we want to find the smallest integer $n$ such that 
$$e^{-n/100}\lt 0.01.$$
Take the logarithm of both sides. We want 
$$-\frac{n}{100} \lt \ln(0.01),$$
or equivalently
$$\frac{n}{100} \gt \ln(100).$$ 
So we want the smallest $n$ such that $n \gt 100\ln(100)$.

Calculate. We get $100\ln(100)=460.517$, so the smallest number of chips that gives probability $\lt 0.01$ of getting a cookie void of chips is $461$.

**Remark:** Note again that a mathematical model and the reality are not the same thing. The number $461$ should be thought of at best as a rough estimate.

Answer (score 0):

If $100$ cookies contain $300$ chips then $1$ cookie contains on average $3$ chips. So $\lambda = 3$. Then we

1. $P(N \geq 2)$ where $N$ is the number of chocolate chips in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here goes...

$300$ chips is a lot of chips. Over $100$ cookies, that works out to $\lambda=3$ chips/cookie.

Now recall for an infinite number of chips,the Poisson distribution gives us the prob of $n$ chips in a cookie as

$$e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$$

so that the prob of having at least $2$ chips in your cookie is approximately

$$e^{-\lambda} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} = 1-(1+\lambda) e^{-\lambda}$$

This works out to $1-4/e^3 \approx 0.801$.  Note we substituted $\infty$ for $300$ in the sum because the difference in the value of the sum is negligible to the level of approximation I am using in the result.

Comment: is it ok ?

The probability of any one chip being in a cookie, p, is 1/100. A chip is either in the cookie or not, so we can use the binomial distribution to model this problem.

P(At Least 2) = 1 - p(0) - p(1)

= 1 - (300C0)(1/100)^0(99/100)^300 - (300C1)(1/100)^1(99/100)^299

= 1 - 0.049041 - 0.148609 = 0.80235

Comment: When the number of samples is very large, the binomial dist. approximates the Poisson dist. very well, so, yes, that's good.